# Issues with useLocation hook in @reach/router

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

I'm using `@reach/router` in my project. According to the documentation, the `useLocation` hook is supported. However, when I try to import it, I keep on getting the same error:

> Cannot import useLocation because there is no useLocation export in
> @reach/router. Did you mean Location?

I've tried deleting `node_modules` and `package.json.lock` and then reinstalling dependencies. Any help?

Comment: which version ?

Comment: Looks like @reach/router is not the issue. Type definition of `useLocation` hooks is missing on Flow (which is probably something I should have added along with my question). Working on updating the types on Flow and raising a PR